# Fast way of deleting white space from right in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Say my cursor is at `demo.getNamesSatisfyingCondition(` line just after `(` character. To have the next line (`LENGTH_FIVE.and(STARTS_WITH_S), names));`) at the same level as `demo.getNamesSatisfyingCondition(` I need to press several times <kbd>Del</kbd> key. Is there a way to do this in a  faster way?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>. The function is called `join lines`.